# Windows Toast Notification Image

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have setup a a Windows Toast Notification but I am not sure how to attach an image to the notification. This is my code for the class:

```
 Class toast_notification
    Public Sub New(text As String, title As String)
        Dim sbXML As New StringBuilder()
        sbXML.Append("<toast><visual><binding template =""ToastImageAndText01""><text id = ""1"" >")
        sbXML.Append(title & vbNewLine & text)
        sbXML.Append("</text></binding></visual></toast>")
        Dim xmlDoc As New Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument()
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(sbXML.ToString())
        Dim toast = New Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification(xmlDoc)
        Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(title).Show(toast)
    End Sub
End Class
```

And this is how I activate it:

```
Dim opening_toast As New toast_notification("text", "title")
```

But how do I get it to show an image like other Windows Notifications, currently it just show text.

Comment: Did you consider reading the [ToastNotification documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification)?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using this:

```
var toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText02);
var stringElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
stringElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("first line"));
stringElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("second line"));
string filePath = path + @"\yourpath\icon.png";
var imageElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");
imageElements[0].Attributes.GetNamedItem("src").NodeValue = filePath;
var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier("Your Programm Name").Show(toast);
```

But I still dont know how to add a logo image (the one at the left top corner when a programm sends a notification).